# Date conversion from string on non-US system

Tags: vb.net, date

My application works for systems in the US, however for some other regions it is returning this error:
"Conversion from string "8/31/2016" to type 'Date' is not valid".

Here is one code sample:
dte_BuildDate_Current = CDate(str_BuildDate_Current)

Any thoughts on addressing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Parse` method where you can pass specific culture you expect date string to be in.

```
Dim dateAsString = "8/31/2016"

Dim culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
Dim currentDate = DateTime.Parse(dateAsString, culture)
```

Actually I would suggest to use `<type>.Parse` or `<type>.TryParse` method over `CDate`, `CInt` or others.
`Parse` methods are more explicit about their intentions, where `CDate` or others similar trying to guess your intentions and do a lot of unnecessary work.